# Contar que no haya 2 String iguales dentro de una condición

Tags: java, java-ee

Tengo la siguiente condición:

```
if (csm.getStatusName() != "CIEX"){
   ....
}
```

Quiero saber como puedo hacer una condición en la que el numero de CIEX no sea superior a 2, es decir, que en la pantalla no me muestre mas de 2 estados CIEX.

Con esa condición lo que hago es con el .getStatusName recojo el estado de un paciente, y quiero hacer que ese mismo paciente no tenga 2 pruebas abiertas con el mismo estado.

Que no pueda haber 2 estados iguales por pantalla.

Saludos.

Comment: No tengo claro lo que quieres hacer, pero no uses `!=`o `==` para comparar Strings

Comment: @PabloLozano Ahí al fin y al cabo estás comparando 2 String, yo lo que quiero es comparar un string con un entero. Lo que quiero hacer es que el csm.getStatusName() != "CIEX" no haya 2 por pantalla

Comment: Hola. No entiendo que quieres, intenta mejorar la explicación editando la pregunta. ¿`csm.getStatusName()` devuelve un entero o un String? Si devuelve un entero y lo comparas con un String tal cual siempre serán diferentes. **Las comparaciones deben ser sobre el mismo tipo de datos** u objetos. **Puedes comparar con la longitud de un string con un entero**, si esto no es lo que necesitas tienen mal planteado tu problema.

Comment: Tu pregunta esta muy mal planteada. No se entiende exactamente lo que buscas.

Comment: que es un estado ciex? O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien. para ponerlo simple. Tal y como han comentado ya, tu error es que comparas dos `String` con el operador `==`, mientras que deberías hacer la comparación con el método `equals` de la clase `Object`, que compara si dos objetos son iguales.

Lo que deberías hacer, por tanto, es recorrer la lista de pruebas del paciente y utilizar un contador que va aumentando con cada prueba con un estado igual (método `equals`) a la cadena de caracteres deseada, para más tarde comprobar si dicho contador es igual a 2 con el operador igual `==`.

```
int contador = 0;
for (Prueba p : paciente.getPruebas())
    if (p.getEstado().equals("CIEX")) contador++;
if (contador == 2)
    System.err.println("Situación no permitida");
```

Te explico un poco el por qué de tu error.

En Java, una variable puede contener un valor de tipo primitivo o bien apuntar a un objeto, de ahí la orientación a objetos. Además, para no perder orientación a objetos, existen las clases envoltura de tipos primitivos (como `Integer` para `int`).

```
int entero = 31;            // la variable "entero" contiene el valor 31
Objeto obj = new Objeto();  // "obj" apunta a un objeto de la clase Objeto (hipotética)
```

Esto ocurre porque cuando creamos un objeto, a dicho objeto se le asigna un identificador de objeto (OID), que es el valor que se almacena en la variable que va a apuntar al objeto creado, y es un valor numérico entero.

```
Objeto obj = new Objeto();  // se asigna el OID del objeto creado a la variable obj
```

Por otro lado, el operador `==` compara los valores numéricos que contienen dos variables.

```
int entero1 = 31;  // se asigna el valor 31 a la variable entero1
int entero2 = 31;  // se asigna el valor 31 a la variable entero2
if (entero1 == entero2)  // se compara los valores de las variables (¿31 es igual a 31?)
    System.out.println("Iguales");  // la igualdad se cumple (31 sí es igual a 31)
```

Ahora bien, existe un método en la clase `Object` de la que heredan todas las clases, que se llama `equals`. Su implementación por defecto es comparar los OID de dos objetos.

```
// variables que pueden apuntar a objetos de la clase Object (real)
Object objeto1, objeto2;
// Creamos dos objetos y asignamos sus OID  a las variables
objeto1 = new Object();  // OID A (50 por ejemplo)
objeto2 = new Object();  // OID B (51 por ejemplo)
// ahora los comparamos
if (objeto1.equals(objeto2))  // En este caso, se aplica el operador ==
    System.out.println("Iguales");  // Si los OID de los objetos coinciden
else System.out.println("Diferentes");  // Si los OID no coinciden
```

Ahora, como ejemplo, vamos a suponer que al crear el objeto "obj", la máquina virtual de Java (JVM) asigna el OID 31 al objeto creado.

```
int entero = 31;            // se asigna el valor 31 a la variable entero
Objeto obj = new Objeto();  // se asigna el OID 31 a la variable obj
if (entero == obj)          // se compara el valor entero 31 con el OID 31
    // Error: 31 es igual a 31, pero un entero no es igual a un objeto
    System.out.println("Iguales");
```

No debería compararse un valor entero con un OID, salvo que manejemos OIDs a pelo (raro raro).

Finalmente, las clases que heredan el método `equals` de `Object` (todas, directa o indirectamente), pueden redefinir su comportamiento para que no compare OIDs, sino el contenido del objeto apuntado por el OID.

```
public class MiClase {

    private String atributo;

    public MiClase(String s) {
        atributo = s;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;  // objeto no ha sido creado, no es igual a this
        if (obj == this) return true;   // OIDs coinciden: mismo objeto
        if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) return false;  // objetos de clase distinta son distintos

        MiClase otro = (MiClase) obj;  // casting

        return atributo.equals(obj.atributo);  // se compara el valor del atributo
    }
}
```

Ahora, el operador `==` y el método `equals` para objetos de `MiClase` son distintos. El correcto a utilizar es `equals`.

```
MiClase objeto1 = new MiClase("Objeto");  // OID: A; atributo: Objeto
MiClase objeto2 = new MiClase("Objeto");  // OID: B; atributo: Objeto
// objeto1 == objeto2 devuelve false (¡Error!) porque A != B
// objeto1.equals(objeto2) devuelve true (¡Correcto!) porque el atributo es igual
```

Comprobemos todos los casos.

```
MiClase miObjeto = new MiClase("Mi Objeto");  // OID A (MiClase)

miObjeto.equals(null);  // Devuelve false (primer caso: nulo)
miObjeto.equals(miObjeto)  // Devuelve true (segundo caso: identidad)

Coche miCoche = new MiCoche();  // OID B (MiCoche)
miObjeto.equals(miCoche);  // Devuelve false (tercer caso: distinta clase)

MiObjeto contenido = new MiObjeto("Mi Objeto");  // OID B (MiClase)
miObjeto.equals(contenido);  // Devuelve true (cuarto caso: contenido)
miObjeto.equals(new MiClase("Objeto2"));  // Devuelve false (cuarto caso)
```

Cabe destacar que `String` no es un tipo primitivo, sino una clase. Por lo que las variables de tipo `String` no contienen valores, sino OIDs que apuntan a objetos.

```
String s = "Hola";  // s apunta a un objeto que contiene la cadena "Hola"
```

Y como apunte final, los literales cadena se compilan como un solo objeto.

```
String s = "Hola";  // s = OID A
String t = "Hola";  // t = OID A
```

Que sería lo mismo que:

```
String h = "Hola";  // h = OID A
String s = h;       // s = h = OID A
String t = h;       // t = h = OID A
```

Entonces, ¿como se consigue que `s` y `t` apunten a objetos distintos (tengan OIDs diferentes)?

```
String h = "Hola";  // h = OID A; contenido: Hola
String s = h;       // s = h = OID A; contenido: Hola
String t = new String(h);  // t = OID B; contenido: Hola
String u = new String("Hola");  // u = OID C; contenido: Hola
```

Los objetos apuntados por `s` y `t` son distintos, pero su contenido es el mismo, por lo que se considera que son iguales por contenido (en la mayoría de casos el OID no importa, lo que importa para una igualdad es el contenido de los objetos).